# Issues with scanf()

Tags: c, struct, scanf, fgets

I have a program I'm using (quiet simple) that requires an input from the user using scanf. These values are stored into a struct array. Anyways, I think I have all of the syntax down correctly (if I don't please correct me), but whenever I want to printf to see the results, I don't get a value from ID[i].Middle_Name. It seems as though it's empty, for reasons I don't understand. I tried to add a print statement to try and debug it but still nothing. Maybe I'm missing something?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdarg.h>

struct Students{
  char First_Name[20];
  char Last_Name[20];
  char Middle_Name[20];
  int Age;
};

int main(void){
    int n = 0;  //number of students
    int i = 0;      //counter

  printf("Please enter the total number of students in your class: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  struct Students ID[n];
  printf("\n");

  printf("******************** \n");
  printf("After entering student info, they are displayed in full_name/middle_name/age order. \n");
  printf("******************** \n");

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      printf("Please enter the first name of student with  ID: %d \t", i);
      scanf("%s", (ID[i].First_Name));
      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the last name of student with ID: %d \t", i);
      scanf("%s", (ID[i].Last_Name));
      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the middle name of student ID: %d \t", i);
      scanf("%s", (ID[i].Middle_Name)); 
      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the age of student ID: %d \t", i);
      scanf("%d", &(ID[i].Age));
      printf("\n");

  }
  printf("In your class, we have: \n");
  printf("%s", ID[1].Middle_Name);

  for(i = 1; i <= n; i++){
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].First_Name); 
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].Last_Name); 
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].Middle_Name); 
      printf("%d \n", ID[i].Age); 
  }
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: What's your input format?

Comment: start index in C is 0 not 1, therefore your for should start with i=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to start with `i = 0` instead of `i = 1` to get the first element of your array. And you should replace the `i <= n` by `i < n`.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, and surprisingly that solved it. Can you explain why that was the case? Why was that different as apposed to my previous method. Shouldn't there be a value there for ID[i].Middle_Name regardless of the position of the array?

Comment: @RenegadeJ The first element of an array is at the index 0. By writing 'ID[1].Middle_Name', you were looking for the middle name of the second element of your array. If you did your tests with only one element in your array, ID[1] doesn't exist and should result in an out of bound error. In other words, if you create an array with 10 elements, the last element will be at index 9 and the first at index 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to replace scanf ("%s", id[i]. ...) with gets
eg.

```
gets(ID[i].Middle_Name);
```

And also start from 0 in the loop instead of 1

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
.....
}

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will do. Also, the starting with 0 actually fixed it. Do you happen to know why that is? I mean it shouldn't matter where it starts as long as you address the same/correct array index, right?

Comment: You are right, If you have accidentally pressed space in the last name then that too might have caused that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{

//Your input code

}

for(i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{

      // your output code

}
```

Comment: You will loop one too many times if you keep this condition. You have to replace 'i <= n' by 'i < n'. ;)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

there an wrong syntax in your code

```
struct Students ID[n];
```

array length must be a const number,or you can use new like this

```
struct Students *ID = new struct Students[n];
```

Comment: ID[n] is correct, is a VLA. Your "new" is C++ not C.

Answer (score -1):

```
// <-- note leading ' ' on all format strings
// <-- always check returned value from input statements
// <-- following line would try to access past end of array, 
//     arrays start with offset of 0,
//     for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <stdarg.h>

struct Students
{
  char First_Name[20];
  char Last_Name[20];
  char Middle_Name[20];
  int Age;
};

int main(void){
    int n = 0;  //number of students
    int i = 0;      //counter

  printf("Please enter the total number of students in your class: ");
  if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &n) )
  {
      perror( "scanf failed reading num students" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  struct Students ID[n];
  printf("\n");

  printf("******************** \n");
  printf("After entering student info, they are displayed in full_name/middle_name/age order. \n");
  printf("******************** \n\n");


  for( i=0; i< n; i++ )
  {
      printf("Please enter the first name of student with  ID: %d \t", i+1);
      if( 1 != scanf(" %s", (ID[i].First_Name)) )
      {
          perror( "scanf failed for first name" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }

      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the last name of student with ID: %d \t", i+1);
      if( 1 != scanf(" %s", (ID[i].Last_Name)) ) // <-- check returned value
      {
          perror( "scanf failed for last name" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }

      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the middle name of student ID: %d \t", i+1);
      if( 1 != scanf(" %s", (ID[i].Middle_Name)) ) // <-- check returned value
      {
          perror( "scanf failed for middle name" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }

      printf("\n");

      printf("Please enter the age of student ID: %d \t", i+1);
      if( 1 != scanf(" %d", &(ID[i].Age)) ) // <-- check returned value 
      {
          perror( "scanf failed for student age" );
          exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
      }

      printf("\n");
  } // end while

  printf("In your class, we have: \n");
  printf("%s", ID[1].Middle_Name);

  // <-- following line would try to access past end of array, arrays start with offset of 0, not 1
  //for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
  {
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].First_Name);
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].Last_Name);
      printf("%s \t", ID[i].Middle_Name);
      printf("%d \n", ID[i].Age);
      printf("\n"); // put each student on a new line
  } // end for
  return(0);
}
```